# opening file returns error 5 in qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to open a file for reading using qt and it doesn't open it, it returns an error 5. I don't know why ?

```
loadObjModel("box.obj");
  QFile obj_file(path) ;

    QString errMsg;
    QFileDevice::FileError err = QFileDevice::NoError;
    if (!obj_file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        errMsg = obj_file.errorString();
        err = obj_file.error();
        qDebug() << QString(" err %1").arg(err) ;
    }
    if (!obj_file.open(QFile::ReadOnly))
    {
        qDebug() << QString("cannot open %1").arg(path) ;
        return ;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you open it twice? Does the file exist? What does `QFile::exists()` return? What does the error description say?

Comment: You're already retrieving errorString(), now print it :)

Comment: What is the error? You should change `qDebug() << QString(" err %1").arg(err)` to `qDebug() << QString(" err %1: %2").arg(err).arg( errMsg )`

Comment: It seems like you're making assumptions as to what is the current working directory of your executable, and the file doesn't exist since the working directory doesn't agree with what you imagine it to be. The only safe cross-platform assumption is that the working directory is random, not necessarily readable nor writable. You must explicitly set it to e.g. the folder where your application was started `qApp->applicationDirPath()`, or another known location.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving this answer here for people with questions about QFile error code debugging in the future.

---

**QFile.error()**

Qfile.error() returns an error number from the following list of errors, taken from the documentation [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledevice.html):

[image]

So if you were to run this snippet of code with an OpenError, the result would be a FileError code:

```
qDebug() << " Could not open file for writing:" << obj_file.error();
```

> Could not open file for writing: 5

---

**QFile.errorString()**

The error code (5) indicates the general class of error, but to dig deeper into the reason behind the error, a more handy function is the errorString() function (which is assigned to errMsg in the question):

```
qDebug() << " Could not open file for writing:" << obj_file.errorString();
```

> Could not open file for writing: "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

By using the errorString() function, you can then get a more detailed error message, and figure out whether your open is failing due to it being used by another process, or the path not existing, and resolve your issue accordingly.

Hope this helps for anyone that sees this question in the future.